# Not able to Run celery-prometheus-exporter

Tags: docker, celery, exporter, airflow

I am trying to  run this online Celery exporter to send metrics to Prometheus .
But the command gets stuck without any logs and  ' docker ps ' shows that container is running.
But the port is still inactive .
[image]

---

[image]

Imho all the dependencies are added
but not able to figure out why it is not working.

It is available as a python package as well. There also i see the same issue

Some links which may be helpful :

https://hub.docker.com/r/zerok/celery-prometheus-exporter

Comment: You didn't specify the `BROKER_URL` so probably it hangs trying to connect to the default which most probably is not available?

Comment: @TomášLinhart  Even if i  explicitly mention the broker url.. I still get that.

Comment: Ok..I got it , My redis was in different network than the exporter..had to expose the port .